# Copy x lines at a time from a file, then paste them in (^v) in Python

Tags: python, macros

I am having issues getting the following code to paste correctly. The idea is it reads 'n' number of lines from a file then moves those lines to the clipboard and pastes them to wherever the users cursor location is at.

Ideally I would have a file that looks like this:

```
the dog says bark
the cat says meow
```

The program would read these two lines to a string (next_n_lines) and then paste them, but the output i'm getting is "["the,dog,says,bark\nthe,cat,says,meow"]". I need the new lines and the spaces to show up as they would if I just copied those lines manually.

```
def main():
    from itertools import islice
    import win32com.client, time, pyperclip
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    userfile = raw_input("Please enter the file you wish to open\n(must be in this directory): ")
    file1 = open(userfile, "r+")
    n = 18
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
        print ''.join(next_n_lines)
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        pyperclip.copy(next_n_lines)
        shell.sendkeys("^v")
        break
    pass

    file1.close()
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Fixed it myself.

```
def main():
    from itertools import islice
    import win32com.client, time, pyperclip
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    userfile = raw_input("Please enter the file you wish to open\n(must be in this directory): ")
    file1 = open(userfile, "r+")
    n = 18
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
        print ''.join(next_n_lines)
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        pyperclip.copy(''.join(next_n_lines)   #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(''.join needed to be added
        shell.sendkeys("^v")
        break
    pass

    file1.close()
```

Comment: what is `magic` n? why to sleep(3)?

Comment: magic n would be the number of lines at a time I want to copy/paste. Lets say if I was pasting to something that only allowed 50 lines at a time I would set n to 15.

In this case n is set to 18 and islice only takes 18 lines at a time.

Sleep 3 is so you can get the mouse into position

Comment: "the dog says bark
the cat says meow". Point of inquiry: what does the fox say?

Comment: my work is on the sensitive side and I am not very creative when it comes to fake data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a line from my code. The code below works.

```
def main():
    from itertools import islice
    import win32com.client, time, pyperclip
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    userfile = raw_input("Please enter the file you wish to open\n(must be in this    directory): ")
    file1 = open(userfile, "r+")
    n = 18
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(file1,n))
        print ''.join(next_n_lines)
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        pyperclip.copy(''.join(next_n_lines)   #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(''.join needed to be added
        shell.sendkeys("^v")
        break
    pass

    file1.close()
```

Comment: please accept the answer, so that the question doesn't remain open.